# Change listitem background based on content/variable

Tags: android, listview

I have a list with a custom adapter and would like to set the background color based on content of the list item or a variable.
The list consists of a textview with a date and some information.

I need the background color to change when a new date is shown..

item1: 2. march 2016 -> blue

item2: 2. march 2016 -> blue

item3: 3. march 2016 -> grey

item4: 4. march 2016 -> blue

...

Could I set an variable (isNewDate) that could be used in the listAdapter?

My list adapter:

```
    public class HistoryListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HistoryListItem> {

        public HistoryListViewAdapter(Context context, List<HistoryListItem> items) {
            super(context, R.layout.history_list_item, items);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;

            if(convertView == null) {
                // inflate the ListView item layout
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history_list_item, parent, false);
                //different color if new date

                if (newdate == 0) //How to find if it is a "new date"
                    //togle color

                convertView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorPrimaryDark));

                // initialize the view holder
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.ivIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
                viewHolder.tvTextfield = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTextfield);
                viewHolder.tvNote = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvNote);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                // recycle the already inflated view
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            // update the item view
            HistoryListItem item = getItem(position);
            viewHolder.ivIcon.setImageDrawable(item.icon);
            viewHolder.tvTextfield.setText(item.textfield);
            viewHolder.tvNote.setImageDrawable(item.note);

            return convertView;
        }

        private static class ViewHolder {
            ImageView ivIcon;
            TextView tvTextfield;
            ImageView tvNote;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by isNewDate and what is the criteria you have to change the background color of list items?

Comment: isNewDate was a suggestion of a variable that could be true og false depening if the background color should be the same as the last item, or toggle to the second background color.

The criteria is "if(the list item contains information from a different day than the last item) { toggle background color}"

Each list items contains information for a specific day. There could be zero, one or many items for each day.

The list data are stored in a db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add varible to store date in **HistoryListItem** model class.
Then your adapter class will look like this.

```
 public class HistoryListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HistoryListItem> {

//Varible to STORE current Date value
String previousDate = null ;

        public HistoryListViewAdapter(Context context, List<HistoryListItem> items) {
            super(context, R.layout.history_list_item, items);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;

            if(convertView == null) {
                // inflate the ListView item layout
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history_list_item, parent, false);
                //different color if new date

                //This is how you How to find if it is a "new date"
                if(null== previousDate || !item.dateField.equalIgnorecase(previousDate))
{
//Store current date as previous date
previousDate = item.dateField ;

 //TODO add togle color logic here
}


                convertView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorPrimaryDark));

                // initialize the view holder
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.ivIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
                viewHolder.tvTextfield = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTextfield);
                viewHolder.tvNote = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvNote);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                // recycle the already inflated view
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            // update the item view
            HistoryListItem item = getItem(position);
            viewHolder.ivIcon.setImageDrawable(item.icon);
            viewHolder.tvTextfield.setText(item.textfield);
            viewHolder.tvNote.setImageDrawable(item.note);

            return convertView;
        }

        private static class ViewHolder {
            ImageView ivIcon;
            TextView tvTextfield;
            ImageView tvNote;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Just had to move HistoryListItem item = getItem(position); before "item" is used..